# How to plot KNN decision boundary in Python from scratch?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, classification, knn

I need to plot the decision boundary for KNN without using sklearn. I have implemented the classifier but I am not able to plot the decision boundary. The plot should be as described in the book ElemStatLearn "The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction. Second Edition" by Trevor Hastie & Robert Tibshirani& Jerome Friedman. The plot required is shown below:

[KNN k=15 classifier Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWv6L.jpg)

So, far I have been able to plot only the image below:

[KNN k=15 classifier Plot produced so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdaCD.png)

I have calculated the grid points and the predictions on those points. I also tried to find the points on the boundary if the predictions don't match with the prediction on the previous grid point and sorted the points. But when I plot the points, they don't look like the one that is required.

```py
def get_grid(X):
    # Creating grids for decision surface
    ## Define bounds of the surface
    min1, max1 = X[:, 0].min() - 0.2, X[:, 0].max() + 0.2
    min2, max2 = X[:, 1].min() - 0.2, X[:, 1].max() + 0.2
    ## Define the x and y points
    x1grid = arange(min1, max1, 0.1)
    x2grid = arange(min2, max2, 0.1)
    ## Create all of the lines and rows of the grid
    xx, yy = meshgrid(x1grid, x2grid)
    ## Flatten each grid to a vector
    r1, r2 = xx.flatten(), yy.flatten()
    r1, r2 = r1.reshape((len(r1), 1)), r2.reshape((len(r2), 1))
    ## Horizontally stack vectors to create x1, x2 input for the model
    grid_X = hstack((r1, r2))
    return grid_X

X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1].astype(int)
# Custom class defined
model = KNNClassifier(num_neighbors = 5)
model.fit(X, y)
y_pred = model.predict(X)

grid_X = get_grid(X)
grid_yhat = model.predict(grid_X)

boundary = []
for i in range(1, len(grid_X)):
    if grid_yhat[i] != grid_yhat[i-1]:
        boundary.append((grid_X[i] + grid_X[i-1]) * 0.5)
boundary_x = [b[0] for b in boundary]
boundary_y = [b[1] for b in boundary]
order = np.argsort(boundary_x)
boundary_x = np.array(boundary_x)[order]
boundary_y = np.array(boundary_y)[order]

def plot_decision_surface(X, y, boundary_X, boundary_y, grid_X, grid_yhat):
    
    figure(figsize=(10,10))    
    axis('off')
    # Plot the ground truth data points in the 2D feature space
    X_pos, X_neg = split_X(X, y)
    scatter(X_pos[:, 0], X_pos[:, 1], facecolors='none', edgecolors='orange', marker='o', linewidth=3, s=60)
    scatter(X_neg[:, 0], X_neg[:, 1], facecolors='none', edgecolors='blue', marker='o', linewidth=3, s=60)
    
    
    grid_pos, grid_neg = split_X(grid_X, grid_yhat)
    
    # Plot and color the grid of x, y values with class
    scatter(grid_pos[:, 0], grid_pos[:, 1], color='orange', marker='.', linewidth=0.05)
    scatter(grid_neg[:, 0], grid_neg[:, 1], color='blue', marker='.', linewidth=0.05)
    
    # Plot the decision boundary for the classification

    scatter(boundary_X, boundary_y, color='k')  
    plot(boundary_X, boundary_y, color='k')
    
    # Plot Info
    show()

plot_decision_surface(X, y, boundary_X, boundary_y, grid_X, grid_yhat)
```

Failed attempt to plot the boundary is shown below:

[Failed attempt to plot the boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX2yV.png)

Comment: The issue is that you are only computing the difference in one direction, whereas you should look at all points in the neighbourhood to determine if a grid-point lies on the boundary. However, matplotlib has inbuilt functions for that so you don't need to implement your own. You can just use `contour(xx, yy, grid_yhat.reshape(xx.shape))` to plot the decision boundary.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the missing direction mistake. I am not allowed to use a library. But I was finally able to implement it by checking in both directions. I appreciate your help.